# What does "You did not earn a trophy" on the PS3 mean?

Tags: technical-issues, achievements, ps3

So the other day I was playing Cars 2 on the PS3 and we got the in-game badge "Tokyo Vandal" and soon after at the top of the screen where it usually would have shown "You have earned a trophy. Tokyo Vandal." it showed "You did not earn a trophy."

I was playing multiplayer and the same trophy has been gotten on some of the other "users" on the system.

Comment: Well, it means that you didn't get a trophy. Are you asking about the mechanics that result in no trophy, or do you think this is a bug?

Comment: How did you create your PS3 profile? Based on various forums, this is a common occurrence if you create a profile by copying from another

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, I think this is a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to different sources, and also @Wondercricket comment:

> This happens when you earn a trophy on your profile with someone else's gamesave.

or

> It's because they used a game save that was linked to another PSN account.

<sub>Sources: [here](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/29940-quotyou-did-not-earn-a-trophyquot/), [here](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/210666-got-the-quotyou-did-not-earn-a-trophyquot-message/) and [here](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/7593-you-did-not-earn-a-trophy/).</sub>